# select an entire row - shortcut keyboard

Tags: python, spyder

I would like to know if there is a shortcut keyboard to select an entire row when I m coding and for example my cursor is in the middle of the row. (I use spyder for python)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows (not sure for other systems) you can use `Shift` + `Num Lock 1` if you are at the start of the line and `Shift` + `Num Lock 7` if you are at the end of the line.

When you are at another point of the line you can press `Home`, leave it and then press `Shift`+`End`

You can find much more information [here](https://superuser.com/questions/947296/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-select-the-entire-current-line-in-notepad).

Comment: Please leave a comment if it works or not in other systems.

Answer (score 0):

Select the active line by pressing `Ctrl`+`W` several times. `Ctrl`+`W` selects the current word, and pressing it again will select the active line.